# How to display current page URL using get_permalink function including query string in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to display the current post/page URL in the front end using the get_permalink function. The following code is working fine but it doesn't print the query string. How can I display the whole URL including the query string(s)?

````
// Shortcode: [current-url]
function current_url() {
return get_permalink($post->ID);
}
add_shortcode( 'current-url', 'current_url' ); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

use this code for it

```
function current_url() {
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request );
}
add_shortcode( 'current-url', 'current_url' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the code didn't work. It doesn't print the parameters. It shows the URL without the trailing slash.

Comment: you can explode it with / . print_r(explode('/', home_url( $wp->request ))); use it